# Trying to use a list to populate a dataframe column

Tags: python

I have a dataframe (`df`) and I would like to create a new column called `country`, which is calculated buy looking at the region column and where the region value is present in the EnglandRegions list then the country value is set to England else its the value from the region column.

Please see below for my desired output:

```
    name  salary         region B1salary country
0  Jason   42000         London    42000 England
1  Molly   52000     South West          England
2   Tina   36000   East Midland          England
3   Jake   24000          Wales            Wales
4    Amy   73000  West Midlands          England
```

You can see that all the values in country are set to England except for the value assigned to Jakes record that is set to Wales (as Wales is not in the `EnglandRegions` list).  The code below produces the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/stacey/Documents/scripts/stacey.py", line 20
    df['country'] = np.where((df.loc[df['region'].isin(EnglandRegions)),'England', df['region'])
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

EnglandRegions = ["London", "South West", "East Midland", "West Midlands", "East Anglia"]

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'salary': [42000, 52000, 36000, 24000, 73000], 
        'region': ['London', 'South West', 'East Midland', 'Wales', 'West Midlands']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'salary', 'region'])
df['B1salary'] = np.where((df['salary']>=40000) & (df['salary']<=50000) , df['salary'], '')
df['country'] = np.where((df.loc[df['region'].isin(EnglandRegions)),'England', df['region'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue the error is referencing is that you are missing a ] to enclose your .loc. However, fixing this won't work anyways. Try:

`df['country'] = np.where(df['region'].isin(EnglandRegions), 'England', df['region'])`

This is essentially what you already had in the line above it for `B1salary` anyways.